# Node Js Lambda runtime error cant find 'util'

Tags: node.js, webpack, lambda

This has has me stumped and thought I would reach out for support. I am currently deploying node js Lambda function and keep running into the following error.

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'util'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'util'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

I am confused as to why in Lambda Node JS 12.x function it cant find a core node module? For reference I am using Webpack with the below config. I am intentionally targeting node to reduce bundle size for the Lambda.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // Change to your "entry-point".
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.ts',
        authoriser: './src/authoriser.ts',
    },
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Include ts, js, and jsx files.
                test: /\.(ts|js)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: you can't compile a package on a Lambda, you will need to compile it yourself and run it on your Lambda

Comment: to clarify the function is compiled as part of a CI/CD toolchain. The output is effectively an index.js file which the Lamba consumes.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to figure out - but turns out a package was pulling in RUST/WASM which was causing the failure. The issue is explained much better here https://github.com/apollographql/federation/issues/255